# How to send conditional props from Parent to Child. (send if only array is not empty)

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I want to show the JSON data I got from an API in `Choices` Component.

```
class ShowChoice extends React.Component{
    // var out=this.props.output Why is it not working here? Why is it showing error?
    render() {
        var out=this.props.output // Why is it not working above render????
        return(
            <div>Render out[0].id here </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`output` is an array which has

```
output =[{'id':1}, {'choice_text':'some choice'}]
```

The problem is that whenever I start the app or the app re-renders itself, the **output** is undefined and it throws an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

for `console.log(out[0].id)`

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. I thought if I could somehow send the props if only the output has some length then I can solve the problem
3. Why is the commented line  `var out=this.props.output` not working above `render`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check first if the ***output*** is defined before rendering anything. 
Like

```
class ShowChoice extends React.Component{

    render() {
        const { output } = this.props
        if (!output) {
           return null;
        }
        return(
            <div>Render output[0].id here </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above `var out=this.props.output;` is not working put inside the constructor its working

```
<pre>
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   var out=this.props.output;
  }
</pre>
```